# ts rule noImplicitAny does not seem to work

Tags: typescript

I have this error when importing components from one of libraries:

> Could not find a declaration file for module
> 'react-leaflet-universal'.
> '/path/node_modules/react-leaflet-universal/dist/index.js'
> implicitly has an 'any' type.   Try `npm i --save-dev @types/react-leaflet-universal` if it exists or add a new declaration
> (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'react-leaflet-universal';`

And from what I've learnt, setting `"noImplicitAny": false,` in tsconfig.json should help with that problem, but it just does not work. I'm still getting same error.

Here is tsconfig.json file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: have you tried running `npm i --save-dev @types/react-leaflet-universal` ?

Comment: yes, there is no such package unfortunetly.